# Laptop battery indicator problem in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, laptop, indicator, battery

After I installed Ubuntu 14.04 (before I had Ubuntu 13.10), the battery indicator stopped working properly. It always shows the battery level that was at the start up (when I open the laptop and boot Ubuntu), and is never updated. I checked the battery state in terminal by the command `acpi -V | grep Battery` and it works fine. So the is problem only with the battery indicator in the panel, not with the battery or the laptop. How to fix this problem?

Comment: How many batteries does the indicator show?  Sometimes a bluetooth mouse battery shows up and confuses things.

Comment: Only one battery, I don't have bluetooth mouse.

Comment: The problem is that the indicator is not updating. If I reset it than it shows the correct battery level but than it again stucks at that new level.